# Remove country code and asterisks from currency formatting of price on frontend

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We use Shopware 6, V6.4.16.1, community edition. Currently we are only selling in the United States and US Dollar.

When product prices are listed on the frontend, the auto formatting updates them to include the US country ISO code, dollar sign, and an asterisk. The end formatting looks like this: **US$2,999.00***

We would like to update the formatting to remove the Country Code, asterisk, and cents. Ideally the above price would look like this instead: **$2,999**

This occurs on landing pages, listing pages, and product detail pages. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here's an example of the product price formatting currently: [image]

1. I've tried removing all other currencies and countries from our Shopware settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most secure way to achieve this globally I can think of would be to decorate the `CurrencyFormatter` service.

```xml
<service id="My\Plugin\Decorator\CurrencyFormatterDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\System\Currency\CurrencyFormatter">
    <argument type="service" id="My\Plugin\Decorator\CurrencyFormatterDecorator.inner"/>
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\Locale\LanguageLocaleCodeProvider"/>
</service>
```

```php
class CurrencyFormatterDecorator extends CurrencyFormatter
{
    private CurrencyFormatter $decorated;

    public function __construct(CurrencyFormatter $decorated, LanguageLocaleCodeProvider $languageLocaleProvider)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        parent::__construct($languageLocaleProvider);
    }

    public function formatCurrencyByLanguage(float $price, string $currency, string $languageId, Context $context, ?int $decimals = null): string
    {
        $currency = $this->decorated->formatCurrencyByLanguage($price, $currency, $languageId, $context, $decimals);

        return str_replace('US$', '$', $currency);
    }
}
```

For the asterisk go to Settings > Snippets within the administration. Edit the base file `messages.en-GB`. Search for `general.star`. The entry with the asterisk should show up. Double click the column with the asterisk and replace the asterisk character it with a single space. Click the checkmark button to save. The asterisk should be gone in the storefront.

Comment: Do you know where the "US" comes from? I cannot see that in our demo - see my answer.

Comment: It's retrieved from either the Symfony intl component or from the intl php extension if you have it installed. The formatting is basically a standard depending on the given language.

Comment: But when is the symbol configured in the admin then used?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this in our Shopware 6.4.16.1 demo store. It displays only `$` when switching the currency to USD.

Are you sure your currency symboly is not set to US$ in `/admin#/sw/settings/currency/index` -> click USD -> Symbol? Because then you could simply change it there and would not need coding.

Comment: It depends on the current language. In german the currency is represented with just the currency symbol. In english the currency code is added. It's a convention carried out by the `intl` component/extension.